# Call onDestroy() with menu button but not with back button on closing app in android?

Tags: android

I want that when i close app with back button on device then my thread should

1. send data to server.
2. update GPS (lat,long) and get notification(on specific place) means do not call
   onDestroy() but when i close app with menu button on device then app should totally
   closed and stop all background updation.(means should call onDestroy()).

Please help me ,i am new to android.

Comment: could you explain your situation a little bit clearer. I really don't get what you'd like to do. Best Regards

Comment: here is my onDestroy method 'onDestroy(){handle.removeCallbacks(sendData);locman.removeUpdates(this;}'

Comment: @safari,i have to close app two ways first with device's back button which leave background thread to run.second i created exit button on menu which will stop all thread

Answer (score 1):

Override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) in your activity to decide what to do when the back button is pressed. And call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) from wherever you want to finish your activity. Never call `onDestroy()` directly.

Comment: ,Thank you i am trying as you guided.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to move your removal code stuff away from `onDestroy()` to a better place, as you cannot prevent `onDestroy()` of being invoked by the System when the activity is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `onDestroy` will be called if system is low on resources, but not because you closed application. I think the better ways is override `onBackPressed` in your home activity and implement your logic, what do you want to do when you are closing application.